# Passing a struct pointer as paramater in C#

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, struct, parameters

I need to include a .dll which contains the following C/C++ function prototype and struct definition:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned short us1;
    unsigned short us2;
    unsigned short data[16];
} myStruct;
int myFunc(myStruct *MYSTRUCT);
```

To use this Function i created a new Class:

```
static class DLL
{
public struct MyStruct
    {
     public ushort us1;
     public ushort us2; 
     public ushort[] data;
     public PDPORT(ushort[] temp1, ushort temp2, ushort temp3)
     {
         us1 = temp2;
         us2 = temp3;
         data = temp1;
     }
    };
    [DllImport("PDL65DLL.dll")]
    public static extern int mvb_PutPort(ref MyStruct CommData);
}
```

In my main class I initiliaze the struct variable and call the Function like that:

```
    DLL.MyStruct communicationData = new DLL.MyStruct(new ushort[16], new ushort(), new ushort());
             DLL.MyFunc( ref communicationData);
```

However, this does not seem to work. The Function is passing something but not the right values, I suggest it is something with the pointer usage. Maybe a struct* is not the same as ref struct... Can someone explain what the problem is?

Comment: slight observation: the export is `myFunc`, and the `extern` is `mvb_PutPort` with nothing to tell it the new name; is that just a copy/paste thing? because: that also won't make things happy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to specify the packing of the struct (depending on the default packing used by the C++ code). You can also specify a fixed-sized array for the marshalling to take care of using `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]`.

You also don't need the C# implementation to use a `struct` and indeed for the fairly large size of the data I would recommend using a class.

Here's an example:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=4)]
public sealed class MyStruct
{
    public ushort   us1;
    public ushort   us2;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
    public ushort[] data;

    public MyStruct(ushort[] temp1, ushort temp2, ushort temp3)
    {
        us1  = temp2;
        us2  = temp3;
        data = new ushort[16];
        Array.Copy(temp1, data, Math.Min(temp1.Length, data.Length));
    }
}
```

Note how the constructor ensures that the size of the array is correct. You must always ensure that the size of the array matches the `SizeConst` declaration.

With these changes, the Marshaller should take care of things for you.

Comment: The program crashes if i use a class object pointer as a parameter (ref Object).

Comment: Nevermind I realized that class objects are already references and needs to be passed by value. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The C/C++ struct is more like a "fixed buffer":

```cs
    unsafe struct MyStruct
    {
        ushort us1, us2;
        fixed ushort data[16];
    }
```

This is not the same as an array, and is a little more awkward to work with in the C# code, but: it is possible.

I'm not 100% sure, but I *believe* you should also use an unmanaged pointer in the P/Invoke layer:

```cs
public static extern int mvb_PutPort(MyStruct* CommData);
```

which means you need to call it via:

```cs
fixed (MyStruct* ptr = whateverYouWereGoingToPass)
{
    mvb_PutPort(ptr);
}
```

Comment: I would avoid using `unsafe` and instead use `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]` for the fixed-size array.

Comment: @MatthewWatson then post that as an answer :) personally, I'd use a fixed buffer

Comment: I wouldn't use `fixed` because then you have to enable `unsafe` for the project - and then it will spread to all the other projects that use that class.

Comment: @MatthewWatson yup, I'm familiar with the implications (all good reasons why I'd keep those types localized to whatever uses them directly), and again: if you have a better approach - that'd make a great second answer

Comment: Lets say I have a function where I initialise "MyStruct test_struct" and set test_struct.data[0] to 10. How do I pass it as a pointer to the fixed-block?